# Discharge / Bleeder resistors

Tags: resistors, discharge

I need to size and build a bleeder resistor network or could be as simple as two bleed resistors....im not sure but I have an application where a we have a step up transformer from 120VAC single phase to circa 1200VAC on the O/P side. When we power up the line, and the line could be anywhere from 5 to 120km with cross sections ranging from 6mm to 25mm for each of the conductors, ie L(6mm) and N(6mm) for application 1 and L(25mm)/ N(25mm) for application 2 they obvious act like a capacitors ie when we switch the power supply off, there is still a residual charge in the line. We then have to "dump" that to earth before we can work on it or you get a shock. So, question is, where to put the bleed resistors in the circuit, on the 120VAC "input" side of the XMFR or do they have to be on the O/P side? If they have to be on the output side, how do i connect them so they are not in circuit when the transformer is on but when it is switched off they are activated? Finding relays / contactors etc for 1200VAC rating is difficult. Also, We would need to bleed the circuit within approx 5 to 10 mins, so how do we go about sizing the resistors? The 1200VAC power supply is approx 2.5kVA rated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the residual charge would be DC, anything on the 120V AC mains side of the xfmr can't very well bleed it. However, if a slight loss of efficiency if acceptable, you could place a 1Mohm to 1.2Mohm resistor from L to G on your output. it would only bleed about 1-1.2mA of current (about 1.2-1.5W) during operation, but your 5-10 minute "powerdown time" gives 300-600 seconds for that "trickle" resistor to discharge the line significantly.
Alternatively, if you can source/afford/build an inductor with a similar resistance at your AC frequency, your efficiency loss would be similarly minimal (attaching the inductor from L to N, same as resistor), but would appear as nearly a "dead short" to 5he stored, capacitive DC charge, and most likely discharge the capacitance below 1V in >0.25sec after mains input power is cut.

Comment: So if I placed a 1Mohm to 1.2Mohm resistor with a hold off voltage rated for the 1200VAC from L to G and similarly if I placed a 1Mohm to 1.2Mohm resistor with a hold off voltage rated for the 1200VAC from N to G that would work?

Comment: also, you said it would reduce the discharge significantly, but how much is that? I presume if I wanted to discharge quicker we would play with the resistance / current etc and try to figure out and possibly take an acceptable loss of efficiency? I also like the sound of the inductor.........

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by hold off voltage here, as I was referring to simply installing the pull-down resistors as "always connected" from L to N (N should normally already be tied to G with <1ohm resistance unless you're using a "floating neutral" system). The resistor would waste about 1.2-1.5W of power during normal operation, as the cost of having them in there for safety. Of course, if accessible, the inductors would be the best/safest/most efficient option (faster mains-off discharge, even if you used inductors with >2Mohm reactance @ 60+hz).

Comment: In order to tell you how quickly the resistor(s) would lower the voltage to any specific level, I'd have to know the actual, tested capacitance of the entire system, in order to be able to run the equations for stored columbs@voltage to total stored emergy, vs rate of discharge through the resistor(s). Also, while an inductor appears as an incredibly low impedance (short) to the stored dc, the resistors will slow their discharging speed as the voltage drops, and you'll want to add a "short to ground" protection device before having any personnel touch the lines.

Comment: I mean the resistor will need to be rated sufficiently for the 1200VAC. So a 1 or 1.2Mohm pull down resistor rated for 1200VAC connected between line and ground always connected would work? I think its a floating ground ie L is 1200VAC and N is 0V tap output from the xfmr. in which case would I be better off using a 1200VAC rated relay (or something else, im open to suggestions as 1200VAC relays / contactors are not that easy to come by) to put the resistors in circuit when o/p is switched off and out of circuit when the o/p is switched on.

Comment: That way I wouldn't get the losses of a permanent bleed right? So when xmfr turned off, L will be tied to gnd via a relay contact and have bleed resistor to gnd and also same for N? And when turned on they are both isolated from gnd?

Comment: If you're wanting to only "turn on" the resistors for the bleed-down (after cutting feed power to the xfmr), then far lower resistances can be used (1.0-1.2Mohm was selected to minimize energy loss when constantly connected). Also, most resistors have rated _wattages_, rather than rated _voltages_. while a 2mm sma chip resistor obviously can't stop 1200 volts from arcing aroumd itself, most resistors rated for >=5W will probably be 1.2kv-safe imo.

Comment: After a little bit of research, you could use 5 TE Connectivity 6-1625984-0 (http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/6-1625984-0/A103855-ND/2731197) 47Kohm/50W resistors in parallel L-G and 5 more N-G, they could safely dissipate the power from fully discharging your lines in 1sec. per ~21uF capacitance in your lines (for about $43 of resistors at current digikey prices). Using your 5-10min. acceptable delay, this would allow for fully discharging up to ~12.75mF of line capacitance. If this works for your application, all that remains is to find a >1.2kv DPST/DPDT switch/relay to use.

Comment: ok just managed to find some info on the cables, for 25mm conductor it apparently has 5uF per km this application was 115km.

Comment: apologies....... 5x10(-8) F/km not uF/km

Comment: the other application was 10mmsq conductors and had 8.7x10(-8)F/km. length was approx. 45km

Comment: I have been using Caddock resistors and was planning on trying to utilize some of their power resistors for the bleed but not sure how to calculate the numbers I need first. how did you get to the 47kohm and 50W? finding the 1200V DPST/DPDT is not easy and I need it to be automatic, ie controlled via 24V or ideally via a 120V circuit interlocked to the MCB with aux contact would be ideal, hence the reason I was looking at contactors and relays. only thing I have found so far though is some 1200VAC rated SSR relays, but not much out their that I can find.

Comment: I chose to look @ 50W resistors to be able to dump a significant amount of stored power quickly. I then computed (1200/50)*1200 to get a 28.8K minimum resistance to keep below a 50W discharge at 1.2KV. Then I simply selected the nearest-value, least-expensive resistor with at least 25% more resistance (for a safety margin)

Comment: Multiplying the above capacitance/km rates & km distances yielded ~9.67uF capacitance, or an estimated  <0.5sec delay for fully discharging the lines (assumong 0 line resistance & 0 line inductance), using 5 47Kohm/50W. resistors im parallel between L-G and 5 more between N-G.

Comment: I know its been a while since this discussion but i eventually got around to revisiting this & calculated this all out with the 28.8K ohm resistors + the 25% margin which came out at 36K and then looked at the 47k resistors as you suggested. Capacitance =9.67uF. When i calculated the time to discharge using 47K ohm resistor it came out at (T=RC) T=0.45s. Time to fully discharge =5T=2.3s. My question is what was your reasoning for needing 5 resistors in parallel for L to Gnd and 5 for N to Gnd? From the calcs i did, it seemed like 1 resistor in each application would work?

Comment: 5 in parallel will safely discharge the line in 20% of the time 1 would take. Also, since there is a very real chance of a technician being killed if the line fails to discharge, 5 in parallel gives you 4 "backups" for each resistor, to ensure the line is still bled down even if 1 resistor should fail & leave an open circuit. For the price of each resistor, compared to an accidental death, I think using the climber's addage "5 times over safety margin" makes sense..

Comment: I fully agree! i just wasn't sure if your reasoning was for safety alone or i had messed up my calcs somewhere! Thanks for your help!